# textarea.selectionStart in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

With this code I can check the caret position in a textarea in firefox:

```
document.getElementById("myTextArea").selectionStart
```

This doesn't work in IE 8. How can I get the caret position in IE 8?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answers here: [Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea)

**Edit**

I sorted out the line breaks issue in IE and posted an answer here: [Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea/3373056#3373056)

Comment: Hm, still not perfect because empty lines in the textarea produces problems (Which is also mentioned in a comment of the linked question), but I think this is the closest I can get. Thanks.