# How can I get the caret position if there is no <meta> tag on the page

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, meta-tags, getselection

I have two test pages: page M and Page NM. They are both identical, in that they have one input textbox. The only difference is that M has a meta tag, and NM doesn't.

The meta tag looks like this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"/>
```

Of course, IE=9 or IE=8 would also work. The edit control could be a textbox, password, textarea, contenteditable div, what have you. I can always find the current caret position using either

```
document.getElementById('ControlName').selectionStart.toString()
```

or

```
window.getSelection().focusOffset.toString()
```

This doesn't work on the NM page. How can I get the caret position when there is no meta tag on a page? Thanks for looking

Comment: repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235411/is-there-an-internet-explorer-approved-substitute-for-selectionstart-and-selecti and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628323/textarea-selectionstart-in-ie and........ you get the point :P

Comment: Turn off compatibility view.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/06/17/compatibility-view-and-smart-defaults.aspx

Comment: Sean, I used those questions to get to where I am now. But I find those solutions useless when the meta tag is not present in IE. I was hoping this question could stand by itself for a page that doesn't have a meta tag.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that that particular method is a non-standard, IE-only mechanism of getting the caret position. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/455732), a nice plugin for jQuery, which will accomplish what you are trying to do in IE 8, 9, or 10 and any other modern browser.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use plugins, sorry, should've mentioned that earlier.